# which framework should i choose from zend or symfony with respect to more customization

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, symfony1

I have been using joomla for 2years . The only problem with joomla is that i have less control over customization .

I am thinking of learning new framework so that i make my own little cms in case i need to design the site from scratch.

ia m thinking of having

```
1)Registration Form
2)members ARea
3)Login System
```

so that i can have small base packagae and then i can build the new site from there.

I am confused which framework should i choosen Zend or symfony.
I am ready to learn any but just thought if anyone can guide

Comment: This has been asked many many times before on SO.  Please use the 'Search' box top right, or look at the list of Related links on the right-hand side of this page...

Comment: from what you describe why bother? Drupal or Joomla will always beat what you do hands down for a client. If however you want to do the things you describe to learn how to had code them yourself then don't use a framework but buikld it from scratch with the correct patterns.

Comment: For anyone wondering which framework to choose, read and watch Uncle Bob: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853233/1614973

Answer (score 2):

Build it from scratch is always the hardest way to go. But that way you can have the customization that you will not have in other case. If you code you cms with right techniques it will be also more lightweight than any other. But if you want to build using framework I will recommend Codeigniter as it is one of the easiest to learn, very customizable and has the best guides and onsite documentation.
Start here http://codeigniter.com/
And use heavily documentation, which is very easy to read http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 1):

For customisation, Zend. It's very, very decoupled and is in some senses a "framework framework". However, you would probably get up and running faster with other frameworks (such as Symfony).

Whichever framework you use, if you are going to customise it a lot then you probably won't be using the majority of their code. Go with the one whose 'model' (i.e. organisation of files, implementation of MVC, how the 'loader' works) most closely fits what you need.